# Ok Google Go to "Blank"

Tags: maps

Is there a way to navigate to locations using Ok Google?

Similar functionality on the iPhone would be "Go Home."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest **supported language pack**. (You can get in-app updates)

Assuming you already have Google maps installed;

**Set your custom address (e.g school)**

1. On your Android phone or tablet, open the Google Maps.
2. Tap Menu Menu and then Your places and then Labeled.
3. Choose Home or Work (school).
4. Enter the address.

**Note: You must be signed in to set, edit, and see your home and work on the map**

Use voice search and navigation commands

1. Open the Google Maps app
2. Say “Ok Google” or tap Speak.
3. Ask a question or tell Maps to do something e.g **"Ok, Google. "Get directions** to [school]." Alternatively, **"Navigate to school."**

## Edit

If someone's address is in your Google Contacts, you can find their address on the map by searching for their name. If you search for an address, you can see any contacts matching that address.

If you wish to add or manage your google contacts, navigate to [Google contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts).

**Adding an address to a Google contact**

1. Open the Google Maps app .
2. Search for an address.
3. At the bottom, tap the address.
4. Tap Label.
5. Enter the name of someone in your Google Contacts. To create a new contact, tap Create contact.
6. Choose an option:

   - Add home: Add the address as your contact's home address.
   - Add work: Add the address as your contact's work address.
   - Add custom label: Make a new label for your contact's address, like "Friend's house."

**Note: Only people stored in your Google Contacts will show up as suggestions. You won't see contact info for people who are stored on your phone or tablet.**

Credits

1. [Find, add, or hide your Google Contacts on the map](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3131570?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en&oco=1)

Comment: I haven't gotten to test this yet but considered the upvotes I'm going to go ahead and give you the bounty.

Comment: No problem, I tried and tested it myself but if you have any issues don't hesitate to address, so I can assist further.  However unlike Siri, your suggestions are done in google maps and the navigation is automatic and also contacts have to be Google contacts not necessarily phone contacts.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is.  One of the key phrases you may be searching for is:

> "Ok, Google. Show me a map of [place name]."

You may need to press the microphone (voice search) button from Google Search or Maps if Google Now is not activated.

For some reason this seems to do a poorer job of identifying contact addresses than

> "Show me a map of [name of place]." / "Get directions to [name of place]."

Many maps / navigation phrases are documented [here](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6041199?hl=en).

Comment: Does this work for custom contact places

Comment: @LiamWilliam I don't think it works for custom labeled addresses on contacts.  You can, however; name your contacts any way you choose.